# Dihedral group question

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $n,i,j$ are integers. Show that in $D_n$

$(rR^j )(rR^i )(rR^j )^{-1}= rR^{2j-i}$ and $(rR^j )(R^i ) (rR^j)^{-1}  = R^{-i} $.

This is what I got so far

$(rR^j )(rR^i )(rR^j )^{-1}= r(R^jr)R^i(rR^j )^{-1}=r(rR^{-j})R^i(rR^j )^{-1}=R^{i-j}(rR^j )^{-1}$

I don't know how to continue from here. I only stuck with $(rR^j )^{-1}$, if I know how to break it, I can do the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1} a^{-1}$ in any group.

Comment: I wonder if  you know the name of theorem for that?

Comment: @Diane I'm pretty sure there is no name, this is a very basic fact that follows directly from the associativity of the group operation and from the definition of inverse elements.